# Add metadata to a GridFS file via request.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I am having a bit of a struggle here trying to dynamically update the `metadata` property within a an exported Multer GridFS module. This module contains an 'upload engine' that handles uploading files to my database. This is the `multer-gridfs-storage` library.

Here is my GridFs upload module `gridFs_upload_engine.js`:

```
> //Upload Engine const mongoose = require('mongoose'); const path =
> require('path'); const crypto = require('crypto'); const multer =
> require('multer'); const GridFsStorage =
> require('multer-gridfs-storage'); const Grid =
> require('gridfs-stream');
> 
> //Init Upload Engine let gfs; const database = mongoose.connection;
> const mongoDb = process.env.MONGODB_URI || process.env.MLAB_URL;
> 
> database.once('open', () => {   //Init Stream   gfs =
> Grid(database.db, mongoose.mongo);   gfs.collection('uploads'); });
> 
> //Create Storage Engine const storage = new GridFsStorage({   url:
> mongoDb,   file: (req, file) => {
>     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>       crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
>         if (err) {
>           return reject(err);
>         }
>         const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
>         const fileInfo = {
>           filename: filename,
>           bucketName: 'uploads',
>           metadata: 'Add Metadata here'
>         };
>         resolve(fileInfo);
>       });
>     });   } });
> 
> const uploadEngine = multer({ storage });
> 
> module.exports = {   engine: uploadEngine,   gfs };
```

The `metadata` property above is what I need to change. This `fileinfo` object is added by `GridFs` to each file when uploaded. The `req` parameter is where I thought I could access the `req.body` of the route that called this middleware, but it comes back as `undefined`.

Here is my test route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Controllers
const upload_controller = require('../../controllers/uploader');

//Dependencies
const upload = require('../../utils/gridFs_upload_engine');

const { engine } = upload;
//Upload Single File
router.post(
  '/single',
  engine.single('file'),
  upload_controller.upload_single_file
);
```

Here is where I pass in the `GridFs` middleware into my API route. This lets the controller utilize this.

This is my `upload controller`:

```
exports.upload_single_file = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log({ file: req.file });
  res.redirect('/');
};
```

The `console.log` logs out the info of the file that was uploaded with the `GridFs` upload engine as expected.

I know that I need to somehow pass in a parameter to `gridFs_upload_engine.js` somehow. Since this file is an exported module, I am not entirely sure how to accomplish this. I can put this code directly into my API controller and go about it that way, but I want it to be a module that I can call from other controllers.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this by exposing a function that lets me update a variable, that is then used as the `metadata` value.

API Route:

```
//Dependencies
const upload = require('../../utils/gridFs_upload_engine');

const { engine, updateMetadata } = upload;

//Upload Single File
router.post(
  '/single',
  (req, res, next) => {
    updateMetadata('xxxxxx'); //Static test value
    next();
  },
  engine.single('file'),
  upload_controller.upload_single_file
);
```

Here, I added a callback that contained the exposed `updateMetadata()` function from the upload engine. Here I am setting the `metadata` with the exposed `updateMetadata()` function. Afterwards, by using `next()`, `router` moves onto `engine.single('file')` which is what actually handles uploading the file.

Here is the `GridFs` upload engine:

```
//Create Storage Engine
let updatedMetadata;

const updateMetadata = id => {
  updatedMetadata = id;
};

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoDb,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads',
          metadata: updatedMetadata ? updatedMetadata : null
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});

const uploadEngine = multer({ storage });

module.exports = {
  engine: uploadEngine,
  updateMetadata,
  gfs
};
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works properly and as expected so I am not going to question it any further. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

solution above didn't work for and after a bunch of google searches I found this [cant access req.body inside metadata. · Issue #1 · devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage](https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage/issues/1)

and felt silly that I hadn't seen it before you have access to the req when creating the storage engine

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
url: db,
options: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            let metaData;
            if(req.body && req.body.checked){
              metaData = true
            }
            const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
            const fileInfo = {
                filename: filename,
                bucketName: "uploads",
                metadata: metaData ? metaData : null
                
            };
            resolve(fileInfo);
        });
    });
}
```

});